# Google Charts Populating Data Using local code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I am attempting to create a chart similar to this example using this example [https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example.).  I have only modified the data in sampleData.json which now reads...

```
{
  "cols": [
    {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
    {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
  ],
 "rows": [
    {"c":[{"v":"1-2 times","f":null},{"v":300,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"3-4 times","f":null},{"v":12,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"5-6 times","f":null},{"v":146,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"7-8 times","f":null},{"v":202,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"9 or more","f":null},{"v":9,"f":null}]}
  ]
}
```

When I open exampleUsingPHP.html using Safari and Firefox the page is blank.  I have also attempted to use this example http://code.runnable.com/VTTnV-SzcQU_aNH1/google-charts-php-example.  This also does not work when I copy the files to my desktop and open the html file.  I can not figure out why the html page is blank as running getData.php from the terminal returns the data and all the scripts are run through a CDN.  Is it a jQuery issue and if so can't this be fixed by running jQuery through CDN?